# Why is Django Displaying Escaped Strings for Photo URLs?

Tags: python, mysql, django

For some reason, Django seems to be displaying my ImageField URL strings escaped. See below ([ImageWithThumbsFieldFile](http://code.google.com/p/django-thumbs/) uses an ImageField behind the scenes, and I tested it with a normal ImageField as well and the problem still existed.)

```
>>> from … import UserProfile
>>> u = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> u
<UserProfile: johnny's profile>
>>> u.profile_picture
<ImageWithThumbsFieldFile: /static/img/profile_picture.png>
>>> u.profile_picture.url
'http://mysite.com/%2Fstatic%2Fimg%2Fprofile_picture.png'
```

Notice the escaping in the URL. Now, when I query the MySQL database:

```
mysql> select * from ..._userprofile;
+----+---------+---------------------------------+------+
| id | user_id | profile_picture                 | bio  |
+----+---------+---------------------------------+------+
|  1 |       1 | /static/img/profile_picture.png | NULL |
|  2 |       2 | /static/img/profile_picture.png |      |
```

The url is not stored as such. So, I do not believe the problem is the data stored in the database (the url is the default).

I have tried escaping with

```
|safe
```

and

```
{% autoescape off %} {% autoescape end %}
```

to no avail. My setup is Django 1.2.3 with MySQL running under Apache mod_wsgi. The app runs on my staging server under the same setup without issue (also Apache and MySQL). But since the escapes show up in the Python shell, I do not believe the database or server to be the root cause. The good server is running Python 2.7, and the bad server is running Python 2.6.6 (for reasons out of my control...though I doubt that is the issue either).

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you same person who was asking about this on #django IRC a few days back? If not, then try the #django IRC as seems your not the only one. I didn't hang around to see end result of the discussion, but was at least determined that stored right in database and was in model or template rendering that problems occurred.

Comment: Yes, that was me in IRC. Unfortunately, I still have not resolved the issue.

Comment: The problem does not appear to be related to template escaping so using `|safe` or `{% autoescape off %} {% autoescape end %}` won't solve the issue you are seeing in the shell.

Comment: I think this has to do with Amazon S3. I think the Django storage backend stores this because S3 doesn't have folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is due to Amazon S3 not having folders. For some reason the django-storages app outputs the urls this way. I thought it was wrong, but the images are working. Just pretty weird to see the urls like that.